# I have a PHP Application which I want to move to EKS. Docker Image got build successfully but on deploying it is failing reason - Readiness Probe fail

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, fpm

I have a PHP Application which I want to move to EKS. Docker Image got build successfully but on deploying it is failing reason - Readiness Probe fail error -

Get "http://172.17.0.6:80//health.php": dial tcp 172.17.0.6:80: connect : connection refused'.

Getting Error Connection refused

I don't understand Why it is failing on Deployment.

Migration to EKS but getting error on Deploying on EKS

Comment: Please share the logs of your PHP application. Are they showing any errors/warnings?

Comment: Logs are showing this. [27-Apr-2023 08:54:55] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[27-Apr-2023 08:54:55] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: Are you using port 80 in your docker image & k8s manifest as well? Can you share them?

Comment: deployment:
  container:
    name: 
    port: 80
  readinessProbe:
    port: 80
    periodSeconds: 5
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    path: /health.php
  livenessProbe:
    port: 80
    periodSeconds: 5
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    path: /health.php
  preStop:
    httpGet:
      path: /health.php
      # path: /actuator/health/update/DOWN
      port: 80
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20

Comment: and exposing port 80 in docker file

Comment: `http://172.17.0.6:80//health.php` has double slashes in the middle. Try removing the extra slash and see if it works.

Comment: Still the issue persist!

Comment: Without probes, does your deployment/pod serve the application correctly? Does your image work locally on your machine?

 Try removing the probes and running `curl http://172.17.0.6:80//health.php` from another pod  and check your results.

Comment: Issue also occurring on local, can't able understand why it is happening. Docker build and deploy successfully.